# Why does the App Store return different (old) receipts when the app is refreshed - testing in sandbox?

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I am trying to test my auto-renewable subscription using the sandbox. So I am getting the local receipt from mainBundle.appStoreReceiptURL?.path, and sending that to my server which then sends it on to the App Store.  I then parse the response from the app store.  So far so good.  My subscription renewal server code works.

I have two iTunes testing accounts verified, and i have successfully purchased and renewed my auto-renewable subscription products for both accounts.  The problem is, sometimes i get a receipt back from the app store that does not match that of the current logged in iTunes account but of the previous and vice versa. This happens when my app comes in and out from the background or when closing the app and re-launching it. As a result, this messes up my subscription validation for a specific user.  Please can someone advise?

My server code:

```
$base64EncodeReceipt = $_POST['receiptData'];
$response = getResponseFromAppStore($base64EncodeReceipt, $SHARED_SECRET);
echo $response;
```

CONSOLE:
THIS is the result when i exit then re-enter the app after it has gone into the background.  You can see that i am getting a different receipt  from the original_transaction_id.

```
 as user is signed in. check subscription status
StoreObserver.checkSubscriptionStatusAppDelegate()

applicationWillResignActive
checkSubscriptionStatusAppDelegate response json: {
    diff = 267000;
    "expDate_ms" = 1549103558000;
    "expires_date" = "2019-02-02 10:32:38 Etc/GMT";
    isSubscribed = 1;
    "original_transaction_id" = 1000000499551500;
    "transaction_id" = 1000000499563944;
}
regStatus: 1
subScriptionStatus: 1
SUBSCRIPTION UP-TO-DATE
applicationDidEnterBackground
applicationWillEnterForeground
applicationDidBecomeActive
as user is signed in. check subscription status
StoreObserver.checkSubscriptionStatusAppDelegate()
checkSubscriptionStatusAppDelegate response json: {
    diff = "-88695000";
    "expDate_ms" = 1549014602000;
    "expires_date" = "2019-02-01 09:50:02 Etc/GMT";
    isSubscribed = 2;
    "original_transaction_id" = 1000000493992743;
    "transaction_id" = 1000000499335032;
}
```

Comment: Are you using UserDefaults to track values at the app end? It takes about 10 seconds before values you store there actually get written to disk. Thus when testing if you move too fast you can get off by one and see what looks like stale values.

Comment: @matt I am using UserDefaults at the App end.  But i don't quite understand what you wrote.  I use 'original_transaction_id' to track which iTunes account related receipt i am getting.  And this id bounces around to different iTunes account which is how i know i am getting different receipts.

Comment: Well, for example, you say "closing the app and relaunching". If you close-and-relaunch quickly, and if you wrote something into UserDefaults when closing, it won't get written into UserDefaults before launch and when you launch it will look like you're now getting stale data.

Comment: @matt ok I understand. But please could you help and explain this to me - the mainBundle.appStoreReceiptURL?.path - does this not contain all the purchase receipts for the app store for a particular iTunes account? When the app goes into he back ground then back to the foreground, the iTunes account is the same. So why is it, or how is it possible that I get different receipts during this time? –

Comment: I don’t know what’s possible.  I am just trying to eliminate your testing procedure itself as a source of the problem, because I have made that mistake in the past.